# 500gb external hard drive listed with 512b only

Tags: linux, hard-disk, external-hdd, parted, size

Has anyone experienced this problem?

I have a 500GB Seagate external hard drive that recently had some problems. Due to these problems I tried to format but unfortunately the formatting shows an error

When executing the command `sudo parted /dev/sdc -s print` I get the following information:

```
Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognized disk label
Model: (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 512B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

the "Disk" information that should show 500GB is showing 512B not counting the "label" error

Here you can also check the HD size error:
[image]

Has anyone ever gone through something like this and managed to resolve it and get the HD back to its normal capacity?

Unfortunately, gparted does not identify the external hard drive and gdisk reports that there is no GPT or MBR partition and cannot create a very small partition, as shown in gnome-disks

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk is too small to hold GPT data (1 sectors)! Aborting!
```

[image]

I thank the help of all

Comment: Disk label should be gpt or possibly old MBR(msdos). What does this show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` Or does gparted show same errors? Does SmartStatus show drive is ok? That can be checked from Disks, icon in upper right. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: "external hard drive that recently had some problems" -- like hardware problems? Maybe the drive is just b0rked. I don't have hard data, but I've gathered the impression that many think the actual drives used inside external drive enclosures aren't always of the best quality. So maybe just get a new one if it doesn't seem to get to its senses. And even if it does, don't store anything important there, etc.

Comment: As already commented, the drive is faulty.

Comment: Unfortunately, gparted does not identify the external hard drive and gdisk reports that there is no GPT or MBR partition and cannot create a very small partition, as shown in gnome-disks

`$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk is too small to hold GPT data (1 sectors)! Aborting!`

Comment: Is it an SSD?  If not, it's toast.  If it is I may have an idea or two.

Comment: Unfortunately no... it's an external hard drive